# Correct usage of the Apple App Store Badge

Tags: website-design, mobile, apple

Is it against Apple policy / guidelines to create a custom button that links to the App Store, or does it have to be the official App Store Badge?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about graphic design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can only use the official badge. See the [**App Store Marketing Guidelines**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#downloadOnAppstore):

> **Use only the App Store badge artwork provided by Apple.**
>
> Do not modify, angle, animate, rotate, or tilt the App Store badge. Do
>   not use the Apple logo alone. Do not use icons, logos, or graphics
>   from www.apple.com to promote your app. Do not refer to iOS in your
>   communications. Instead refer to the Apple products your app natively
>   supports.

[image]

> The Download on the App Store badge must be legible on all marketing
>   communications in which you promote your app offered on the App Store.
>   For all online communications, you must provide a link to your app on
>   the App Store wherever the badge is used.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To add onto Yisela:

### Affiliate Logo Guidelines and Art

> The iTunes and App Store logos are recognized worldwide and using them
>   correctly is an important part of being an affiliate partner. A few
>   simple guidelines can go a long way in helping your partnership in the
>   affiliate program:
>
> - You must provide a link to iTunes or the App Store wherever a badge is used.
> - iTunes or App Store badges should be used anytime the link is not a text link.
> - **You may never alter the artwork provided except to change the size**. See guidelines for size spec and limitations.
> - You may never use the Apple logo alone.
> - The iTunes desktop icon, or other graphics from iTunes, cannot be used as a representation or link to the iTunes or App Store. iTunes,
>     when used in headlines or text, is always shown as iTunes with a
>     lowercase "i" and uppercase "T" even when it is the first word in a
>     sentence. For the App Store, always capitalize "A" and "S."

[Source](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/affiliate-logo-guidelines-and-art.html)

### Identity Guidelines

> Our badges are recognized worldwide. Proper implementation of badges
>   gives your users clear direction on where to go to buy compelling
>   content. Use the links below to access guidelines and badges for each
>   of our stores.

[image]

[Source](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/identity-guidelines.html)